# how can I use an object property name as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Goal:
I'm trying to create a simple function which checks if a property exists in an object,
if it doesn't, the property is then created and the value is assigned to it.
Problem:
the parameter from the function parameters is not being read.

```
let b = {
  name: 'Chuck Berry',
  job: 'musician',
  bestTune: 'Johnny Be Good',
};

const propertyChecker = (obj, property) => {
  obj.property = obj.property || 'American';
  console.log(obj);
};

propertyChecker(b, 'nationality');
```

console.log:
{name: 'Chuck Berry', job: 'musician', bestTune: 'Johnny Be Good', property: 'American'}
bestTune: "Johnny Be Good"
job: "musician"
name: "Chuck Berry"
property: "American" ---- this should be (nationality: "American")

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are 2 ways to access a property of an object:

1. dot notaion: `obj.property;`
2. brackets notation: `obj['property'];`

If the property is stored in a variable, you can only use the brackets notaion.

You need to change this line:

```
obj.property = obj.property || 'American';
```

to:

```
obj[property] = obj.[property] || 'American';
```

because `property` is a variable.

Comment: Thanks Idan for this concise answer.
So I patched some holes in my JS foundation and as I understand:
the function parameters are variables, therefore my argument from function call becomes a variable, how does that sound?

Comment: @REM yes, and when you pass a variable to a function, a copy of the variable is created. [is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)